# Find pattern in a string variable with Excel Vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a string `v = "word 1, word 2, word 3, ..., word n"`

And I want to check if we find the word 2. If yes display "word 2 exists"

I tried to use the function Find but I think she need a Range however I just have a variable.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: You are looking for the [InStr function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function). It returns the position of the first occurrence in the string. That means if the result of `InStr` is `>0` then the search string was found.

Answer (score 1):

Use `instr()`

```
Sub isItInThere()
    v = "word 1, word 2, word 3, ..., word n"
    If InStr(v, "word 2") > 0 Then MsgBox "word 2 exists"
End Sub
```